# stop asynctask being called twice

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have found my AsyncTask being called twice. To stop this, in my `MainActivity`,I have defined

```
 public Boolean isloading = false;
```

and asynctask is called as:

```
   if (!isloading) {
      new GetFlickr(MainActivity.this, imageViewWeakReference, MainActivity.this)
          .execute(Double.toString(Lat), Double.toString(Long));
    }
```

When asynctask was inside the MainActivity class (i.e., in same file), there was no problem setting isloading = true in PreExecute, as:

```
  @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      pBar = new ProgressBar(getApplicationContext());
      pBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
      pBar.setProgress(0);
      pBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      isloading = true;
    }
```

But, I have moved asynctask to a seperate file, and can't set the value to true there.

Any help please?

Comment: Hi, **I have moved asynctask to a seperate file, and can't set the value to true there** so this is your real question, you can just use `SharedPreference` to set true/false to your variable `isloading`

Answer (score 0):

The trivial thing is just to set isLoading xhecking the value, in the calling code.

```
if (!isloading) {
      isLoading = true
      new GetFlickr(MainActivity.this, imageViewWeakReference, MainActivity.this)
          .execute(Double.toString(Lat), Double.toString(Long));
}
```

This works so long as only a single thread can call the coad that starts the async thread.  If multiple threads can, then you need to move to a lock like a synchronized block.

Comment: Thats what my current solution is. But, I thought (without no basis or proof), that calling it from PreExecute would make sure of not being called twice. Problem is, I am not sure if AsyncTask is called twice or to doInBackGround